# PHP ZipArchive::addGlob() does not work as expected

Tags: php, csv, php-ziparchive

I have a bunch of large CSV files which need to zip for later exports. I thought it should be easy with ZipArchive class but it is not. My code looks like:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$open = $zip->open("$zipDirName/reports.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
if ($open !== TRUE) throw new \Exception("CampaignsDeviceDays::saveCsvDaysDataZip() error. \$zip->open() failed with error code $open");

$addGlob = $zip->addGlob("$tempDirName/*", GLOB_BRACE, ['add_path' => DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'remove_all_path' => TRUE]);
```

This code successfuly creates zip file but it is empty.
I want to have all csv files on the top level in zip file. If I use

```
'add_path' => 'whatever/'
```

it works. But I want to have it on top level.

The second problem is that I want to owerwrite the files which are in archive but do not remove files which has been in archive before I run the script. I tried constants like
`ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE` but it always rewrite all files in archive. But I dont want to generate all files always. I want previous files saved as they are.

How to achieve this simple solution in PHP? I